# Updating and overwriting values of a column of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, updates, overwrite

I have an XLS file wiht this dataframe and I need to update it

```
   V1      V2      V3      V4   V5     V6       V7  V8
1   1   EFNB2   EFNB2   EFNB2   72  0.667  0.05980 YES
2   2    AOC2    AOC2    AOC2  108  0.609  0.13000 YES
3   3     FOS     FOS     FOS  142  0.554  0.19300 YES
4   4   CCNE1   CCNE1   CCNE1  167  0.530  0.25700 YES
5   5    CBX4    CBX4    CBX4  275  0.448  0.26700 YES
6   6    CRY1    CRY1    CRY1  343  0.400  0.29000 YES
7   7 TNFAIP6 TNFAIP6 TNFAIP6  600  0.194  0.18500  NO
8   8    SSX3    SSX3    SSX3  641  0.171  0.18900  NO
9   9    WNT2    WNT2    WNT2 1211 -0.173 -0.08030  NO
10 10   FGF18   FGF18   FGF18 1296 -0.225 -0.09130  NO
11 11    PIM2    PIM2    PIM2 1386 -0.273 -0.09780  NO
```

I am only interested in V7 and V8. Let's say I am applying a condition on V7 values. If applied, I'll update the cell next to it(V8) from NO to YES starting from this cell to last cell of V8. P.S. If V8 = Yes, keep it the same.

Example: 
df(9,V7)= -0.08030 and it satisfies the condition. 
Then the I should access the table and update V8

```
 V1      V2      V3      V4   V5     V6       V7  V8
1   1   EFNB2   EFNB2   EFNB2   72  0.667  0.05980 YES
2   2    AOC2    AOC2    AOC2  108  0.609  0.13000 YES
3   3     FOS     FOS     FOS  142  0.554  0.19300 YES
4   4   CCNE1   CCNE1   CCNE1  167  0.530  0.25700 YES
5   5    CBX4    CBX4    CBX4  275  0.448  0.26700 YES
6   6    CRY1    CRY1    CRY1  343  0.400  0.29000 YES
7   7 TNFAIP6 TNFAIP6 TNFAIP6  600  0.194  0.18500  NO
8   8    SSX3    SSX3    SSX3  641  0.171  0.18900  NO
9   9    WNT2    WNT2    WNT2 1211 -0.173 -0.08030 YES
10 10   FGF18   FGF18   FGF18 1296 -0.225 -0.09130 YES
11 11    PIM2    PIM2    PIM2 1386 -0.273 -0.09780 YES
```

**Update:**
This is the condition it should meet

```
#Checking the change of signs of the 1st derivative of V7 (unlins)
    check_sign <- which(diff(sign(unlins))==-2|diff(sign(unlins))==2 ,1) 
#assigning integrated values of unlins (V7)   
V7_values <- df1$V7[check_sign] #return values of V7 
>> V7_values
[1]  0.2570 -0.1670 -0.0419
```

I tried to use this suggested code,

```
df1$V8[df1$V8 == 'NO' & df1$V7 %in% V7_values] <- 'YES'
>>df1
  V1      V2      V3      V4   V5     V6       V7  V8
1   1   EFNB2   EFNB2   EFNB2   72  0.667  0.05980 YES
2   2    AOC2    AOC2    AOC2  108  0.609  0.13000 YES
3   3     FOS     FOS     FOS  142  0.554  0.19300 YES
4   4   CCNE1   CCNE1   CCNE1  167  0.530  0.25700 YES
5   5    CBX4    CBX4    CBX4  275  0.448  0.26700 YES
6   6    CRY1    CRY1    CRY1  343  0.400  0.29000 YES
7   7 TNFAIP6 TNFAIP6 TNFAIP6  600  0.194  0.18500  NO
8   8    SSX3    SSX3    SSX3  641  0.171  0.18900  NO
9   9    WNT2    WNT2    WNT2 1211 -0.173 -0.08030  NO
10 10   FGF18   FGF18   FGF18 1296 -0.225 -0.09130  NO
11 11    PIM2    PIM2    PIM2 1386 -0.273 -0.09780  NO
12 12   PLCL1   PLCL1   PLCL1 1636 -0.415 -0.16700 YES
13 13     MX2     MX2     MX2 1676 -0.437 -0.12400  NO
14 14   ABCA6   ABCA6   ABCA6 1720 -0.457 -0.07980  NO
15 15 HSPA12A HSPA12A HSPA12A 1788 -0.501 -0.04190 YES
16 16 TNFSF10 TNFSF10 TNFSF10 1944 -0.855  0.00155  NO
```

> but it only updated selected cells of V8 next to where the condition of V7 is met(12 & 15) only. While I need it to start updating from 12 and extend till the end of the table.

**Update:** 
Finally, this worked

```
df1$V8[which(df1$V8 == 'NO' & df1$V7 %in% V7_values)[1]: length(df1$V8)] <- 'YES'
```

Comment: Assigning to a subset, like `df$V8[df$V8 == 'NO' & df$V7 < 0] <- 'YES'`?

Comment: If you want to update everything after a condition is first met you could do: `df$V8[which(df$V7 <= -0.08030)[1]:length(df$V8)] <- "YES"`

Comment: I have updated the question with the condition and warnings result from the two suggested code. do I have to use any write()? or this would be enough to access the file and overwrite?

Comment: The warning is because `V7_values` has three values in it, but `df1` has 11 rows.  Maybe try `df1$V8[df1$V8 == 'NO' & df1$V7 %in% V7_values] <- 'YES'`

Comment: I appreciate your help. I tried this and it worked:
df1$V8[which(df1$V8 == 'NO' & df1$V7 %in% V7_values)[1]: length(df1$V8)] <- 'YES'